# Is it ok to delete an Azure log analytics workspace?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I have inherited an Azure subscription that is 4 basic App Services (websites). It has a log analytics workspace resource in it.

Is there any problem if I delete this resource? The websites all run fine and are very low traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry about deleting the workspace. As log analytics workspace is a unique environment and it can be created to monitor those rescoures which have deployed for a long time. What I mean is that the workspace and other resourse is low coupled.

In the meantime, workspace can be soft deleted, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/quick-create-workspace#troubleshooting

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its absolutely fine deleting the workspace as the operation only delete the Workspace resource manager resource and the data is being kept for 14 days as in soft delete state. As it kept monitoring the analytics and the agents, SCOM (System Centre Operations Management) managements group be in the orphaned in the soft-delete state.

If you want you can even ramp to delete it at a stretch, here is the document for you: [Permanent workspace delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/delete-workspace#permanent-workspace-delete)